# Connect react native app with node js in local system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native

I am trying to connect my `react native` app with my node js app in the `Windows` system. Via `Postman` I am able to get response from node API, but getting `undefined` as response from `react native` app.

**IPv4 Address** :- 192.168.1.5

> Node js / index.js file

```
require('./config/mongoose')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = require('./app')
const port = process.env.PORT

app.listen(8000, '192.168.1.5')
```

> React native files

**axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.5:8000/api/',
  timeout: 10000,
  // headers: headers
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // nothing to do
  },
  function (error) {
    EncryptedStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    EncryptedStorage.removeItem('user');
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';

export default axiosInstance;
```

**function that calls the api**

```
const signIn = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    let token = null;
    let user = {};

    console.log(username +'--'+ password);   // data prints correctly

    await axiosInstance
        .post('login', {username, password})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);   // undefined
            let res = response.data;

            helpers.showToast(res.message);

            if (res.status) {
                // some other staff
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            helpers.showToast(e.message);
            console.log('Error Signin: ', e.message);
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a networking issue but an axios interceptors one. With postman there is no axios and no interceptors, however, your react native code has one and you forgot to return the response in the interceptor:

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    // nothing to do but still return response
    return response;

  },
  function (error) {
    EncryptedStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    EncryptedStorage.removeItem('user');
    axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);
```

Comment: reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

Comment: OMG....thank you so much..!!

Comment: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ngrok](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok)?

```
npm i ngrok -g
```

Then open another terminal. `And run` :

```
ngrok http 8000 // the port you're using on node
```

It will then display an `alternative link` that you can use to test with your Node.

`Then copy the generated link`, e.g. http://8084-167-913-145-700.eu.ngrok.io, and test to see if it solves your problem